# Check if Active Record table has changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sinatra, activemodel

In Active Record I can write `name_changed?` to check if the column `name` has changed.

How do I check if a table has changed? (i.e new records added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use call back inside model to check table condition changed, for example if you want to change record added, here[ActiveRecord Callback sequences](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object)

```
# app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :some_call

  def some_call
    puts "this is your code after record added?"
    # you can also check table condition directly from here
    puts Model.count
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well whenever a record in your table is changed, it changes through create or post action..so If you want to do something whenever a record is added or updated i.e change in table, just do it inside your create action.

Like you can create notifications whenever a user comments by calling create notification inside your create method.

or you can simply count the number of rows using .size or .count on your record

and look for a change in number or size of your table